# React Table background row color based on model property

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a Books list bound to the Table

```
return ( <div>
{books.map((x,i) => ( <tr>
                         <td>x.bookName</td>
                         <td><MyCustomTextInput value={x.price}></MyCustomTextInput></td>
                      <tr></div>);
```

There is also a button "Add new book"

When User clicks on "Add new book", a popup opens so that User can enter the book details.

On the popup when User clicks on "Save new book", I am updating the corresponding array element by adding new book row.

When I add a new book, I set "IsNewBook" property to true

I need to highlight the newly added book row to the table with some color say red

One approach I am thinking of is setting className to the row but how this can be done based on "IsNewBook" property?

Or any other thoughts?

Comment: Has book model "IsNewBook" property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some approaches. But I prefer this:

```
return (
    <div>
    {books.map((x,i) => (
        <tr className={x.IsNewBook && "isnew" }>
            <td>x.bookName</td>
            <td><MyCustomTextInput value={x.price}><MyCustomTextInput/></td>
        <tr>
    ))}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use classname to highlight the row having isNewBook property as 1 as follows

```
<tr class={item.IsNewBook === 1 ? "newbook" : ""}>
```

[Code Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-night-10tgt?file=/src/App.js)